# Installing ipython qtconsole mac osx - can't find pyqt on system

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, homebrew, pyqt5

I have followed the following [steps](http://www.lowindata.com/2013/installing-scientific-python-on-mac-os-x/#ipython) in order to set up a data science environment on my laptop, running osx yosemite 10.10.3.

When I enter the suggested command at the end of the guide "ipython qtconsole" I get an error message which suggests that pyqt is not installed / it does not exist where it is currently looking for it:

"   ImportError: 
    Could not load requested Qt binding. Please ensure that
    PyQt4 >= 4.7, PyQt5 or PySide >= 1.0.3 is available,
    and only one is imported per session.

```
Currently-imported Qt library:   None
PyQt4 installed:                 False
PyQt5 installed:                 False
PySide >= 1.0.3 installed:       False
Tried to load:                   ['pyside', 'pyqt', 'pyqt5']"
```

I have however installed these formulas using brew:

```
brew install qt
brew install sip
brew install pyqt
```

and have confirmed that they now are installed by running the command

```
brew list
```

and confirmed that they are in the outputted list.  So I should have a version of pyqt installed.  After installing pyqt I got the following message output:

==> Caveats
Phonon support is broken.

Python modules have been installed and Homebrew's site-packages is not
in your Python sys.path, so you will not be able to import the modules
this formula installed. If you plan to develop with these modules,
please run:

```
mkdir -p 
echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> homebrew.pth
```

which I did.

So I am not sure how to proceed, I need to tell ipython where the location of pyqt is on my system I assume, but not sure how to do this.

Comment: Install PyQt via MacPorts ~ https://gist.github.com/guillaumevincent/10983814. Then upgrade iPython. The problem should disappear. Also, make sure to install PyQt5. PyQt4 will seize development at the end of this year and PySide is practically abandonware these days.

Comment: Have you updated your $PATH?

Comment: I have updated my path as indicated in the steps I was following, is there anything else I should add?

Answer (score 1):

I added two more steps and I am happily using the `qtconsole`.

```
sudo pip install pyside
pyside_postinstall.py -install
```

It worked for me on OSX 10.10.

Source: The PySide module docs [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same exact problem. This solved it: past `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH` in the terminal to link your brewed packages with your OS.